# C# typed <T> usercontrol in design mode gives error

Tags: c#, generics, user-controls, types, designmode

I've got a custom class, which derives from `UserControl`. 
The code:

```
public partial class Gallery<T> : UserControl where T : class, IElement, new()
```

This classworks like it's supposed to work. But, when I try to enter design mode of the form which contains these `Gallery` classes, it gives me errors:

> - Could not find type 'PresentrBuilder.Forms.Gallery'.
>     Please make sure that the assembly
>     that contains this type is referenced.
>     If this type is a part of your
>     development project, make sure that
>     the project has been successfully
>     built.
> - The variable 'pictureGallery' is either undeclared or was never
>     assigned.

Note: (`pictureGallery` actually is a `Gallery<PictureElement>`).

How can solve this? This way, I can't work in design mode which makes creating my userinterface quite hard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The designer hates (i.e. doesn't support) generic controls, and that isn't going to change any time soon, so don't do that. Instead, consider having a property (or similar) that accepts a `Type`, and do some work at runtime (reflection etc) - or: don't use the designer.

For example, if you have:

```
public Type ControlType {get;set;} // comparable to T in the original
```

You can use:

```
IElement el = (IElement) Activator.CreateInstance(ControlType);
```

This will give you everything you currently have (`new`, `IElement`, etc) - but it just can't do any validation at compile-time.

Comment: Five years have passed since this question was asked. Did something changed in newer versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Definitely not because I'm having the exact same issue now.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes the easiest thing to do in this case is to make an empty subclass that qualifies the generic parameter.

This is often done with the ObservableCollection:

```
public class SomeItemCollection : ObservableCollection<SomeItem>{

}
```

It is kind of irritating, but it may solve your problems.

Answer (score 3):

Like the others have stated, the Visual Studio Designer has a lot of trouble handling generics in controls. I've run into this myself when trying to implement something like a generic 'property viewer' class.

The solution that worked for me was defining an intermediary class, like Egor said. If I understand your question correctly, for your situation, that should be something like this:

```
public class PictureElementGallery : Gallery<PictureElement>
```

Then use the *PictureElementGallery* on your form, instead of *Gallery < PictureElement >*.
The designer should have no trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a generic control, have the control interact with a generic class that is separate from the control itself. Then pass this class into the control.